# how can i move a sprite on touch using cocos2d?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

i have this void function that makes a sprite move if a touch is detected:

```
-(void) ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];

    car.position = ccp(0,10);
}
```

the game runes fine, but when i touch the screen it freezes when its meant to move the car sprite, thanks for your help!!

Comment: Hard to help you with the information provided : what is 'freezes', do you see an error in the log, some kind of message in the debug console ? Also, what is a 'car' object, show where you create this object, and assign the car iVar. All is pretty vanilla in this code, the only 'freeze' I could see is if 'car' is de-allocated when you are trying to set its position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 way is

```
[car setposition:location];
```

it will directly place your car at your touch.
Other way is

```
[car runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1 position:location]];
```

Check for spelling. I dnt have IDE to check every spelling. :)
Hope this helps